# Laravel equvalent query of field +1 on insert data

Tags: php, mysql, eloquent

I want to execute a `sql` query using laravel query builder.My `MySQL` query is given below:

```
insert into $tbl (code,name) values ('code+1','$name');
```

I can do this by using following queries

```
$id = DB::table($tbl)->max('code');
$data = ['code' => $id +1,'name' => $name];
$query = DB::table($tbl)->insert($data);
```

But I want to run only single query but do not want to run two queries for optimizing performance.

**What is the single query for this sql?**

Comment: you can set auto-increment to this column and other way you can use subquery.

Comment: I didn't want to it auto-increment to that columns. because I perform some  incremental value conditionally. I already have an auto-increment id column

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this query..
    Here i am using sub query you can edit and use  this

```
insert into $tbl values (((select max(code) from $tbl as code) + 1), '$name')
```

Comment: Thanks. But I don't want to write sub-queries. I only want to execute this single query just like mysqli

Comment: According to this answer, sub query is slower than join https://stackoverflow.com/a/15899621/4865187

Comment: But as i think  in your case there is a one time insertion query and it no more effect on your application speed. So if you want to use this you can.